# An iOS (or OS X) project depends on two versions of a framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, alamofire

I am writing a swift framework, which depends on Alamofire v3.x. Now I want to add my framework into a project, which depends on Alamofire v2.x. I am using Carthage to manage me project. It seems not possible to add two versions of the same framework in a project. Is there a way to solve such situation?

Comment: What if the two framework versions tried to write to a database in a common location but each version expected a different schema?  You cannot guarantee two versions of the same framework (that you didn't write) can interoperate so you should never mix and match framework version like this.  Use one or the other.

Comment: @par Thank you for your comment. In fact I would like to distribute a framework which depends on Alamofire v3.x, but what if my users are using Alamofire v2.x in their projects?

Comment: It's the same problem. Now Alamofire *in particular* might be compatible across versions (I have no idea) but broadly if you have third-party dependencies in your library you need to tell your users they have to use that version as well if it is also their dependency.  Just think about it in terms of shared resources between the two versions of the same framework and you'll see why things are inevitably going to break (in unexpected, nasty ways).

Comment: @par I think the value in solving the problem, dependency hell, far out weights the edge case scenarios you mentioned. To not solve dependency hell is either asking framework developers to not use dependencies and write all the code themselves or asking framework consumers to do manually dependency version mismatch resolution. Both scenarios seem hellish.

Answer (score 3):

What you encountered is called dependency hell. Runtimes like [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973843.aspx), [Node](http://blog.timoxley.com/post/20772365842/node-js-npm-reducing-dependency-overheads) etc. have solved the problem. Java, at least up to 8, will just pick the first version it finds at runtime and hope all other packages will work with it; they don't.

CocoaPods can detect dependency hell for you and error during `pod install` but that's it. I think Carthage does the same? Then users of your framework are stuck downgrading dependencies here and there until your framework and other dependent frameworks all use the same version of the shared dependency. As of right now, that's still the only option available to us AFAIK.

Apple did kind of solved dependency hell via [Framework versioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/VersionInformation.html). The framework would bundle up multiple versions of itself and when linking against the framework, the linker would record the full path (version is in the path) to the required version. But a framework bundling up multiple versions of itself was and is an incredibly silly idea and so never took off.